# Date doesn't appear in view

Tags: laravel

I have this code to show the conference start date if is not null, if is null show ''. The issue is that in the database the start_date field is not null bot on the page the start date dont appears. Do you know what can be the issue?

```
 {{!empty($draftConference->conference->
   start_date) ? 
   $draftConference->conference->
   start_dateformatLocalized('%a, %b %d, %Y - %H:%M')
            : ''}}
```

$draftConferences shows like:

```
LengthAwarePaginator {#341 ▼
  #total: 1
  #lastPage: 1
  #items: Collection {#340 ▼
    #items: array:1 [▼
      0 => Conference {#329 ▼
        ...
        #attributes: array:22 [▼
          "id" => 2
          "name" => "test"
          "description" => ""
          "start_date" => "2018-10-30 08:30:00"
          "...
        ]
      ...
      }
    ]
  }
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that you drop an arrow between start_date and formatLocalized.

It should be:

```
$draftConference->conference->
   start_date->formatLocalized('%a, %b %d, %Y - %H:%M')
```

and you got:

```
$draftConference->conference->
   start_dateformatLocalized('%a, %b %d, %Y - %H:%M')
```

Also, maybe you want to parse the date, so you dont have problems with Carbon, maybe putting it in this way:

```
\Carbon\Carbon::parse($draftConference->conference->start_date)->formatLocalized('%a, %b %d, %Y - %H:%M')
```

Hope that this works!

Comment: Thanks, but also the date dont appears with "$draftConference->conference->
   start_date->formatLocalized('%a, %b %d, %Y - %H:%M')".

Comment: Also dont appear with "\Carbon\Carbon::parse($draftConference->conference->start_date)->formatLocalized('%a, %b %d, %Y - %H:%M')".

Comment: if you only try to print with \Carbon\Carbon::parse($draftConference->conference->start_date)->formatLocalized('%a, %b %d, %Y - %H:%M')  or \Carbon\Carbon::parse($draftConference->conference->start_date) it shows something or also its empty? (I refer without the statement)

Comment: It shows "ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Trying to get property of non-object".

Comment: and if you only print the $draftConference->conference->start_date it shows the date?

Comment: maybe try with $draftConference->conference['start_date']